# Can I control ports input / output of an industrial robot?

Tags: ros, motoman-driver, motoman, fanuc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to existing drivers of industrial robots (motoman, fanuc) to control ports input / output and to manage them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272675/can-i-control-ports-input-/-output-of-an-industrial-robot?/) by [JADJER](https://answers.ros.org/users/32096/jadjer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2017-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`motoman_driver`: partial yes: infrastructure is there (merged in [ros-industrial/motoman#93](https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman/pull/93)), but ROS API is missing in the official ROS driver. [This commit](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/motoman/commit/f764a07308e35175fe68a851c050611c45b7a5ca) shows how that can be added, and is on the list to be merged upstream. Those commits should apply against current `HEAD` of `motoman`. You need at least `v1.2.4` of MotoROS (on your controller) for that to work.

`fanuc_driver`: partial no: official driver doesn't have it integrated, but there is an implementation of [this REP](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/rep-ros-i/blob/rep-xxxx_generic_io/rep-ixxxx.rst) in [antonxy/industrial_core](https://github.com/antonxy/industrial_core).

One of the reasons why we're hesitant to integrate IO into those drivers is that we don't want to invent (*and* implement, *and* maintain) yet another bus/interface/system for (industrial) IO. There are enough, mature, interfaces already, and we'd rather people use those.

(Re-)using an existing fieldbus immediately also allows people to reuse their experience, existing hardware and tooling and support offered by the mfg of that hardware, which are all great benefits I believe.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1